# Using HttpUtility.HtmlEncode and handling special characters/umlaut etc

Tags: c#, asp.net, utf-8, ascii, html-encode

I'm using `HttpUtility.HtmlEncode` to sanitise user input to prevent against XSS attacks. My problem is that `HtmlEncode` converts special characters like `ü` into their Html equivalent code. I can't find the documentation about what it does and doesn't encode. Then in order to display this correctly back to the user I need to `HtmlDecode` it.

2 questions:

1. How does `HtmlEncode` decide that it needs to encode a supposedly valid character like `ü` and not other unicode characters like standard English alphabet characters. Does `HtmlEncode` encode all non ascii characters? What is the best way to prevent script tags but allow special characters like umlauts without creating a special ignore list?
2. Does using `HtmlDecode` expose a risk as it is converting back potentially malicious javascript

Comment: "My problem is that HtmlEncode converts special characters" Why is that a problem? Your string should either appear as HTML source (then HtmlEncode is right) or appear as plain text (then don't use HtmlEncode )

Comment: It doesn't encode alphabetical english letters to their Html code..

Comment: It doesn't need to. Please tell us what you do with the string and how it is displayed to the end user.

Comment: Why does it need to encode special german and french characters like umlaut and ^

Comment: Because it works on the safe side. All the characters <128 are the same in all different charsets (latin1, ISO 8859-11, ...) so these are always available. Everything above 127 is dependent upon the charset, so better play safe and encode them. Also, you never "HtmlDecode to display" - that is the job of the users browser!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. HTMLEncode() does 2 main things:

   1. It handles any characters that aren't part of the default 127 ASCII characterset.
   2. It encodes characters that could be misinterpreted by the browser as being valid HTML, CSS or Javascript, to prevent both accidental and intentional altering of the webpage.
2. Is it dangerous to use? Everything can be dangerous to use, depending on how you use it. The question is not as much "are you decoding?" but rather "Are you decoding user data?". It can definitely be dangerous to use, depending on what you do with the result. Even just displaying it to the client can cause XSS.

There is FAR more to be told about encoding and decoding than I can write in here, and people before me have explained it far more exhaustive than I can. [This article on preventing XSS in Asp.Net](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff649310.aspx) can explain you what XSS is and how you can prevent it.

Comment: So the set of characters HtmlEncode will work on is = Any non ASCII characters + any ASCII characters which could be mis-interpreted by the browser such as < > etc?

Comment: @user48408 Yes, exactly.

Comment: Assuming that is correct, I'll mark it as the answer. If you have any documentation on that please post in the comments